# Is there a way to connect a USB flash drive to a SATA port?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, sata, usb-to-sata

I have a desktop machine with an Asus x79-Deluxe mobo. Some of the USB ports are unable to detect any USB device like sticks or flash drives. Is there a way to connect a USB device to a SATA port?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Wouldnt you be better solving the USB interface issue or getting a PCI to SATA interface?

Comment: I don't know how to fix the USB interface. Do you know? I have the keyboard and mouse still working and I don't want to put a USB hub and risk ruining those ports and then the mobo is useless. I don't understand your PCI to SATA interface thing. I have USB port issues and I have empty SATA ports. How does PCI help here?

Comment: A decent hub is likely to HELP protect the remaining interface. SATA is an entirely different protocol to USB, so its not just a matter of converting the cables. You can get PCI to USB adaptors which you plug in to your motherbiard fairly cheap which will give you more USB ports. (Google PCI USB)

Comment: Also, are you sure this is a hardware problem? Your motherboard is theoretically quite robust. Have you tried an alternative OS to see if its a driver issue? Also, your motherboard has a USB header for front facing ports. Is this connected? If not, you may be able to take advantage of them with just a cable?

Comment: Also try plugging your keyboard into other ports to see if it works (not working does not prove anything but working can point to a driver issue) Also, look in the BIOS to check no ports are disabled in BIOS.